# How to get checked row values with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have been trying to get a value of a hidden textbox which are model bind using razor. The table consists of 2 hidden input types for each row. I want to get value of the textbox where the **id** says **purDate**.

How do I do this.

Here's the table for references

```
<table id="accounts" class="ui celled selectable table">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Acc No</th>
 <th>Purchased Date</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model.WithdrawelAccounts)
 {
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center">
   <input id="@item.ACC_AC_ID" type="checkbox" class="ui checkbox check" name="example" />
   <input id="accts" type="hidden" value="@item.ACC_NO_OF_AC_CURRENT" style="display:none" />
   </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        @item.ACC_PURCHASE_DATE.ToString("dd/MMM/yyy")
        <input class="pDate" id="purDate" type="hidden" name="purDate" value="@item.ACC_PURCHASE_DATE" style="display:none" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 }

 </tbody
</table>
```

Here's the they way I tried to retrieve the values

```
<script>

$('#frm_submit').click(function (event) {

var purDate = [];

 $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents("td"), function () {
            noOfAcc.push($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').attr("value"));
            purDate.push($('#purDate').val());
            //purDate.push($(this).find("input[id='purDate']").text());
        });
});
 var purDate = [];
</script>
```

As you can see I have tried to get the value using id `purDate` but the result have duplicate values

The output on console.

`purdate (2) ["2/1/2014 12:00:00 AM", "2/1/2014 12:00:00 AM"]`

As you can see it has taken only the first `<td>` value in the loop according to what I think.

The actual result should be

`purdate (2) ["2/1/2014 12:00:00 AM", "2/4/2019 12:00:00 AM"]`

How to I correctly loop and get the values in the table according to my need. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Id must be unique so use class instead of id.

Comment: Please, remove your php code from your example code and add the pure one from browser.

Comment: @reporter not sure that would help as it would remove the for-loop and if there was only one entry in the sample, the id would be unique and wouldn't reveal the problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m Are you sure that object Model.WithdrawelAccounts contains one entry? By removing the php code the questioner would received more readers and allows the helper to rund the html code in his own enviroment.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi!, I have not used any php code here. Only razor model data binding.

Comment: @AshaneAlvis why are you directing that comment to me?

Comment: @reporter do you not see the "if" in "if there was only one entry"?

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry wrong username used. It was meant to reporter. So sorry.

Comment: @freedomn-m I cannot see any "if"s and some other readers either.

Comment: @reporter here's my comment "not sure that would help as it would remove the for-loop and **____if____** there was only one entry" - can you see it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an error in here.

> `$('#purDate').val()`

It gets the first `#purDate` value. Your `id` should be unique. To fix this, you can put this in a class.

Remove the duplicate `id` and move it to `class`.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.WithdrawelAccounts)
 {
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center">
   <input id="@item.ACC_AC_ID" type="checkbox" class="ui checkbox check" name="example" />
   <!-- Remove the accts id-->
   <input class="accts" type="hidden" value="@item.ACC_NO_OF_AC_CURRENT" style="display:none" />
   </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        @item.ACC_PURCHASE_DATE.ToString("dd/MMM/yyy")
        <!-- Remove the purDate id and put in in a class-->
        <input class="pDate purDate" type="hidden" name="purDate" value="@item.ACC_PURCHASE_DATE" style="display:none" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parents("td"), function () {

    //noOfAcc.push($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').attr("value"));
    //purDate.push($('#purDate').val());

    // This will get the closest class in selected checkbox
    noOfAcc.push($(this).closest('.accts').val());
    purDate.push($(this).closest('tr').find('.pDate').val());

    //purDate.push($(this).find("input[id='purDate']").text());
});
```

Comment: Wow. It worked perfectly. This answer worked for me. I marked it as correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
document.formName.elements['purDate'].value
```